# how to display grand totals under line chart and horizontal bar chart under dashboards

Tags: dashboard

I want to display totals of line chart and horizontal bar chart under dashboards. Is it possible to display totals below

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. But with a Gauge or Donut you can which is a more common use case.
Another way would be to use the Analytics Rest API.